# How do I create new volume or directory out of a different partition?

Tags: lvm, proxmox

I'm using Proxmox 6.2. When I was installing it, I've set it to use only a portion of my disk because I was planning of using the remaining space for another partition to contain my VM disks and other stuff.

Now I'm trying to make use of the remaining unallocated space. So I've created another partition and created ext4 file system on it. But when I tried adding that new partition as storage in Proxmox, it just wouldn't show it.

As it seems, Proxmox only shows disks that are totally empty when adding a new volume or directory. It doesn't show the partition nor the disk if it has been partitioned. My goal is to make use of that new partition as storage (new volume or new directory) to contain my VM images.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, there's no way to do this on web interface. The web interface only allows creation of volume group if the disk is entirely unallocated and has no partitions. I had to manually create physical volume, volume group, and logical volumes via command line in which after doing so will make the volume appear on the web interface.

In order for Proxmox to be able to use any of my logical volumes as directory storage, I had to mount it in a specific directory and create the directory via web console and specify the directory where I mounted my logical volume. Only then Proxmox will report its storage capacity including the size of my logical volumes.

I initially thought all of these can be done via web console, but after playing around and taking so much time, I don't think it is possible. If anyone is able to prove otherwise, I'd accept their answer as the accepted answer.